# Should I use the cross validation score or the test score to evaluate a machine learning model?

Tags: cross-validation, model-evaluation

Let's say I want to compare two machine learning models (A and B) on a classification problem. I split my data into train (80%) and test set (20%). Then I perform 4-fold cross-validation on the training set (so every time my validation set has 20% of the data).

The average over the folds cross validation accuracy I get is:

model A - 80%

model B - 90%

Finally, I test the models on the test set and get the accuracies:

model A - 90%

model B - 80%

Which model would you choose?

The test result is more representative of the generalization ability of the model because it has never been used during the training process. However the cross-validation result is more representative because it represents the performance of the system on the 80% of the data instead of just the 20% of the training set. Moreover, if I change the split of my sets, the different test accuracies I get have a high variance but the average cross validation accuracy is more stable.

Comment: Try performing a n-try, K-fold cross validation. For each try, you split the dataset into K folds and when you optimize over a hyperparameter you use the same K folds to get your CV error. Finally, you can plot a boxplot of your hyper parameter on the x-axis and error on the y-axis. This will not give you a nice clean value but will provide a range of values, choose your hyper parameter accordingly. This could prevent the overfitting mentioned by @Berkay Bulut

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't really think that model B is over-fitting. My impression is that the test set (being only the 20% of the dataset) is not representative enough. If a take a different split of the data then model B is better in both metrics. But, is it proper to change the split of your data to get a satisfying result?

Comment: The final goal of every ML model is to get good results for new data. Hence, it is not good to pick a particular split that gives a "lucky" (by setting the seed) result. Looking at your comment below, I would say that sometimes we can even get lucky with the K folds if we perform it only once. Therefore if we perform n-try K-fold we can get an idea of the range of error.

Comment: Yes, this could be a good idea. Ideally, we could also have n-try train-test split and then for each train set have n-try k-fold. However this would require training hundreds of models and unfortunately each training needs a couple of days..

Comment: Nice question! I'm really curious if you actually came across this (if so please post the full data and analysis) or a clever [Gedankenexperiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment)?

Comment: What do you do in the cross validation? Do you use it to tune hyperparameters?

Comment: I actually came across this problem. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to disclose the data. The model was a deep neural network. Cross-validation was performed to tune a few parameters.

Comment: great question!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, if the cross validation results are actually *not* used to decide anything (no parameter tuning, no selection, nothing) then you don't gain anything by the test set you describe:

- your splitting in to training/test is subject to the same difficulties as you subsequent splitting of the training set into the surrogate training and cross validation surrogate test sets. Any data leakage (e.g. due to confounders you did not account for) happens to both.
- in addition, as you say, the 20 % test yset is smaller. Whether this is a problem or not depends largely on the *absolute* number of cases you have. If 20 % of your data are sufficient to yield test results with a suitable precision for your application at hand, then you are fine.

---

That being said, selecting a model is part of the training of the final model. Thus, the selected model needs to undergo independent validation.

In your case, this means: select according to your cross validation, e.g. model B (although you may want to look into more sophisticated selection rules that take instability into account). Then do an independent test of the selected model. That result is your validation (or better: verification) result for the final model. Here: 80 %.
However, you can use an [additional outer cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nested+cross+validation) for that, avoiding the difficulty of having only few test cases for the final verification.

Answer (score 6):

> However the cross-validation result is more representative because it represents the performance of the system on the 80% of the data instead of just the 20% of the training set.

This is not the whole picture. Yes, the cross-validation error uses unseen ("out-of-bag") data. However, note that you are using the CV error in fitting your model and tuning (hyper-)parameters. And then the final model you are working with *has* seen these "unseen" data.

Cross-validation is part of model training. CV errors are not indicative of out-of-sample performance.

This would argue for using model A, which performs better out-of-sample. However...

Note that now you are using your test set in *selecting* a model. Thus, for your final model, the test set is not unseen any more!

Another thought experiment: assume you are fitting a *huge* amount of models to your data (maybe some of these models add random noise to your predictions?) and assess all of these models on your test set. Then one model will perform best on the test set. But if you then choose this model as your final model, its good performance on the test set may be due to chance alone. You may have overfit to the test set.

Conclusion: test set performance is only then a guide to true out-of-sample performance if it is not used in selecting, tuning or "improving just a little bit" your final model.

> Moreover, if I change the split of my sets, the different test accuracies I get have a high variance but the average cross validation accuracy is more stable.

High variance in test set performance is a red flag. It does seem like you are overfitting. You may simply have too little data for your model, and beyond some point, even cross-validation may not save you. Consider regularizing your model, or constraining it in some other way (e.g., using the [one standard error rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/80268/1352)).

Also, [accuracy is not a good evaluation measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is creating test data at 20% of your total data set. However, the main purpose of Cross Validation Testing is to evaluate your models on different random samples loosing minimum information.

It is also important to consider how you cross validate and create your test data, whether you stratify sample the data or straight split. I suggest using stratified sampling in both CV and test for the data to more representative.

The information you present on the accuracy on two different models leads to conclusion that model A can be improved by using more data, it is seems to have underfitted and your model B has overfitted to your train data. These maybe due to the nature of the algorithms you have used, the features in your model, the regularisation you may have used or the sampling/splitting method you have used in the splits.

Comment: "Out-of-bag" refers to samples not included in a particular run of a bootstrap aggregation (bagging) algorithm, not what's happening here. Can you say more about how you came to the conclusions you did in the last paragraph?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The CV is done within the 80% of the training set which is split into 4 for the 4 folds each having 20% of the data. My impression is that model A just got too "lucky" with the test set. However, it was not as much lucky when tested on the 4x20%=80% of the dataset